# Opencart product images stored on CDN (Amazon S3)

Tags: image, amazon-s3, cdn, opencart

I have been using OpenCart for our site, I am really happy with it, it is an awesome platform that comes with many features and a big community around it. I am interested in moving all my images from the local server to some kind of CDN, maybe Amazon S3. I haven't managed to fidn any module for this, so I am considering updating the code. Any idea/guidelines where to start with?

Cheers,
Iraklis

Comment: There are a few people with regards to this issue who have posted about OpenCart and CDN usage. The best mod (rather than coding your own) I have seen is HostJars for MaxCDN. It is commercial: http://opencart.hostjars.com/opencart-maxcdn

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments, I went with CloudCache, there is an extension for OpenCart and it works like a charm :-) http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the CloudCache CDN extension and it works like a charm, http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6351

Answer (score 0):

You can use this new OpenCart module http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=10702
It was developed for Cloudinary CDN.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.